# Not able to modify the javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am not able to modify the object after updating the null value in the object.

Explanation:

1. In the below picture as you can see, I value a check box with value buff1, on selecting the checkbox the input box below it will turn disabled.
2. Now click on the above button 'Apply  '. then the values in the below of it ie., 1 and 2 will be updated in the disabled input boxes.

As you can see in the jsfiddle

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asrf4658/15/)

[image]

Now I need some thing like,

1. When I select the checkbox next to buff1, the input boxes below it will go disabled and then the values inside it will go empty.

   As I tried in the $watch statement

Example:

```
//modifyObject(list, 'SS', '');//Try uncommenting these 2 lines
//modifyObject(list, 'AA', '');
```

2. And then clicking on the 'Apply ' button, then the value should have updated, but it is not happening

I believe some thing is going wrong in this

Now you guys understood the question, Please let me know if you need more 
explanation.

I feel the problem is here

```
var modifyObject = function(object, key, value) {
            Object.defineProperty(object, key, {
                value: value,
                writable: true,
                enumerable: true
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue come from the attribute checked of the checkbox, if you take a look, "bufferValue.checked" is a String, then "false" or "true" are true twice.

I recommend you to write the ng-disabled something like this :

```
ng-disabled="bufferValue.checked == 'true' && bufferValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a one a working example that you want, when you checked the checkbox the value will reset to 0 and click will apply the value to the input below.

http://jsfiddle.net/asrf4658/21/

I saw that you have a one missing function ng-click="setGlobalvalue()"

```
$scope.setGlobalvalue = function(status){
  if(status) {
    $scope.bufferValues[0].SS = 0;
    $scope.bufferValues[0].AA = 0;
  }
}
```